# Java readLine() is returning null

Tags: java

The "Number of Lines = 4" shows it's reading all 4 lines of the text file. 
But then "Line read = null". I don't know why the readLine() method is not reading the first line.

```
import java.io.*;
public class TestLineRead {

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
      try
      {
          File tmpFileIn = new File("C:/Java/Employees.txt");
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(
                  new FileInputStream(tmpFileIn)));

          LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(br);
          int numOfLines = 0;

          while (lnr.readLine() != null) {
              numOfLines++;
          }

          String str = null;
          System.out.println("Number of lines = " + numOfLines);
          str = br.readLine();
          System.out.println("Line read = " + str);

          br.close();
      }
      catch (IOException e) { System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage()); }

  } // close main
} // close Class
```

Comment: It is reading. But after the `while` loop, it will have read all the file, so no lines will be left. So, when you do `str = br.readLine()` it will return `null`, as the file end has been reached with the previous loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't know why the readLine() method is not reading the first line.

It did, when you were counting lines.

This

```
while (lnr.readLine() != null) {
    numOfLines++;
}
```

consumes lines. It returns `null` when there are no more lines left.